# Python datastructure for map like access

Tags: python

I need a container in python which I can access like/or similar to this:

```
map = buildMap()

versionA = map['A'].version
osA = map['A'].os

versionB = map['B'].version
osB = map['B'].os
```

Anything like this in python (from 2.7 and down)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class and a dictionary, where you can map the instances of the class with key strings, like this

```
class OSMap(object):
    def __init__(self, os = "", version = ""):
        self.os = os
        self.version = version

os_map = dict()
os_map["A"] = OSMap("Windows", "7")
os_map["B"] = OSMap("Ubuntu", "13.10")
print os_map["A"].version, os_map["A"].os
print os_map["B"].version, os_map["B"].os
```

**Output**

```
7 Windows
13.10 Ubuntu
```

Alternatively, you can use [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), like this

```
from collections import namedtuple
OSMap = namedtuple("OSMap", ("os", "version"))

os_map = dict()
os_map["A"] = OSMap("Windows", "7")
os_map["B"] = OSMap("Ubuntu", "13.10")
print os_map["A"].version, os_map["A"].os
print os_map["B"].version, os_map["B"].os
```

**Note:** `namedtuple` objects cannot be changed later, as they are derived from `tuple`.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Good point but they cannot be altered later on. :( Still, adding that option as well.

Comment: The property of immutability is all good news. :) +1 for `namedtuple`

Answer (score 0):

Well you have `dict` that does what you are looking for.

```
my_map = dict()
my_map['A'] = {'os': 'osa'}
my_map['B'] = {'os': 'osb'}
```

It is a dictionary whose values are dictionaries themselves.